# DrawPrimitive with alpha

Tags: c++, c, directx

I'm trying to draw a line with the `DrawPrimitive` function in Direct3D.

Can I draw tranparent line with the function?
If I can, how to design it?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a DirectX expert, but I don't believe transparency has anything to do with the `DrawPrimitive()` function specifically.

I would look into the `SetRenderState()` function to enable alpha blending, and then assign some color/texture properties to your geometry.

Also, if you are just drawing a single line you may not see anything since a line by itself wouldn't have any width. I'm guessing you actually want to draw some triangles or quads or something instead of just a line.

Comment: Line width can be set, I think (you can on some hardware, not sure if it's part of DirectX or not).  If not, they are single-pixel-width, and you can in fact see them.  :)